# How does this code start a C-style string with index 1?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
const int MAXN = 100;
char s[MAXN];
cin >> s + 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(s); i++) {
    cout << s[i];
}
```

My friend wrote this code. I wonder what `cin >> s + 1` actually means. In this situation the C-style string starts with index `1` and ends with index `strlen`. I am confused, because C-style strings start with `0` and end with `strlen - 1`.

Comment: This is your friend being cheeky and making the c-string a 1-based index instead of 0-based.  I would not suggest doing this as you waste space and fly against standard convention which wastes the time of everyone else that looks at the code.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sure, but they are inputing into `s+1` and starting the for loop at `1` so it's pretty clear they are trying to make a 1-based index c-string

Comment: @NathanOliver: I deleted my comment after realizing it was probably wrong. (I hadn't noticed that the following code was performing input into the array, not output from it.)

Comment: OP can you explain your edit? The change from `strlen(s+1)` to `strlen(s)` makes the code wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-style string is just an array of bytes. You can index into an array however you like (as long as you stay within its bounds). The code in the question is simply ignoring the first element of the array (the element at index 0).

Perhaps you can understand the code better if you introduce an alias for the expression `s + 1`:

```
const int MAXN = 100;
char s[MAXN];
char *t = s + 1;
cin >> t;
for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(t); i++) {
    cout << s[i]; // which is the same as t[i-1]
}
```

Note that the condition `i <= strlen(s + 1)` is dubious: it will include the terminating NUL character in the output.

Comment: It's also dubious because it unnecessarily calls `strlen()` on each iteration, making the loop O(N**2).

Comment: The strlen in the original loop is `strlen(s)` and not `strlen(s+1)` which begs the question "what is in the first character?" because if it is a 0 then the loop won't run at all.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The question had `strlen(s + 1)` before an edit.

Answer (score 1):

`char[]` can be used as a `char*`, so doing `s+1` simply says start reading from `s[1]` or `++s`, so using `std::cin >> s+1` will leave `s[0]` uninitialized by you.

Comment: *char[] is essentially a char** Please don't perpetuate that.  You can use an array name like a pointer in a lot of cases, but an array is not a pointer.  It's size is part of its type and there are a lot of things you can't do to an array that you can to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Should we discuss original code

```
const int MAXN = 100;
char s[MAXN];
cin >> s + 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(s + 1); i++) {
    cout << s[i];
}
```

or after edit

```
const int MAXN = 100;
char s[MAXN];
cin >> s + 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= strlen(s); i++) {
    cout << s[i];
}
```

Second one could get `0` form `strlen(s)` if `s[0]` is equal `0`. Additionally it steps over ending `NUL` character.

In first one, `cin >> s + 1;` reads data from standard input and puts it starting with `s[1]`. `for` loop starts form `1` so first outputted character will come from `s[1]`. The only tricky part is `i <= strlen(s + 1)`. Normally we write `i < strlen(s)`. Because there is `strlen(s + 1)` `i` would not reach `NUL` character.

Let assume that after `cin` we get "_ABCD0" (`0` means NUL character - not 0 digit, `_` means untouched `s[0]`). `strlen(s + 1)` will yield 4 so last index with `i < strlen(s + 1)` would be 3 which points to letter C. We can correct this by `i < strlen(s + 1) + 1` or `i <= strlen(s + 1)`.

It could work but it extremely increases probability of "off by one errors". Highly not recommended.

`cin >> s + 1;` could cause buffer overrun. Use `std::string` instead of raw pointer.